# `TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()`

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2` :

```
df1:
    day_search
    0
```

Here each row of day_search is a `<class 'numpy.int64'>`

```
df2:
        day_search
        0
        0,1
```

Here each row of day_search is a `<class 'str'>`

For `df2` dataframe, this code works fine :

```
for _, row in df2.iterrows():
  list_day_search = [int(s) for s in row['day_search'].split(',')]
```

But for `df1` dataframe, this code raise an error : `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'split'`

If I modify with :

```
for _, row in df1.iterrows():
  list_day_search = [int(s) for s in row['day_search'].split(',')] if len(row['day_search']) > 1 else  [int(s) for s in row['day_search']]
```

This code works fine on `df2` but on `df1`, I get `TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()`

First have you a little bit more elegant solution in ths last code and how to fix this error please ?
Thanks a lot.
Best regards.

Comment: If values are strings `'0,1'` what is expected ouput? Because `0,1` integers not exist, close is `[0,1]` list of integers. For one value `0` is changed to `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If need create list of integers change:

```
[int(s) for s in row['day_search'].split(',')]
```

to:

```
[[int(x) for x in s.split(',')] if isinstance(s, str) else s for s in row['day_search']]
```

Solution change only strings to lists of integers.

If use:

```
[[int(x) for x in s.split(',')] for s in str(row['day_search'])]
```

all values are converted to lists, it means also `1` to `[1]`, `'0,1'` to `[0,1]`.

Comment: Thanks but I get "
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'" on df2